# Python Pattern Matching with Regex

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

So I have this text file named righthops.txt that contains a bunch of lines that all look like:

```
12  engrish.net (216.70.106.32)  19.491 ms  22.252 ms  22.147 ms
12  engrish.net (216.70.106.32)  15.214 ms  19.502 ms  37.143 ms
12  engrish.net (216.70.106.32)  15.832 ms  15.804 ms  15.738 ms
```

So I have this code that opens the text file and reads it in. Then I am attempting to use regex's findall command to extract only the last time delay in each line (22.147, 37.143, 15.738). I didn't want to get too complicated so I was planning on doing a pattern match that would get the last two time delays in each line and I could later use a for loop to take in every other element in the list into a new list with only the last time delays.

To do this I tried to make the pattern take in any digits following the 'ms' which in theory would take in the last two time delays in each line but for some reason my code (shown below) isn't taking in anything at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
hops = open('righthops.txt')
righthops = hops.read()
alldelays = re.findall(r'ms (\d+\.\d+)', righthops)
```

Comment: Looks like there's more than a single space between columns.

Comment: Why don't you just iterate line per line, match `\d+\.\d+(?=\s*ms\s*$)` and do whatever you like with it?

Answer (score 1):

If all of your files are formatted identically, then regex is probably overkill. In this case it is much simpler to just go by the indexing on `split()`

```
with open("righthops.txt", 'r') as hops:
    for line in hops:
        last_delay = line.split()[-2]
```

You'll obviously have to modify the above to save each delay to whatever data structure you'd like.   Also note that I've used the `with` context manager just as a convenience thing (avoids needing `hops.close()` later)

If the file is particularly large, you'll want to do a line by line approach to prevent having the entire file stored in memory (which your current approach wiht `re.findall()` does)

Answer (score 0):

Split on whitespace, take the second to last element.

```
d = """12  engrish.net (216.70.106.32)  19.491 ms  22.252 ms  22.147 ms
12  engrish.net (216.70.106.32)  15.214 ms  19.502 ms  37.143 ms
2  engrish.net (216.70.106.32)  15.832 ms  15.804 ms  15.738 ms
"""

for l in d.split("\n"):
    if " " in l:
        print(l.split()[-2])
```

Output

```
22.147
37.143
15.738
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @Lutz Horn recommended:

Split your text file by newline and then use re.findall as follows:

```
collector = []
y = '''12  engrish.net (216.70.106.32)  19.491 ms  22.252 ms  22.147     ms
12  engrish.net (216.70.106.32)  15.214 ms  19.502 ms  37.143 ms
12  engrish.net (216.70.106.32)  15.832 ms  15.804 ms  15.738 ms'''


for line in y.split("\n"):
    x = re.findall(r"(\d{2}.\d{3} ms\s*)", line)
    collector.append(x[-1])
```